# Overriding messages PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a WP plugin but my messages are overriding eachother.

This one below

```
add_filter('login_errors',create_function('$a', "return 'Operation failed!';"), 5);
```

overrides ALL my login errors. So when I'm blocked from logging in, it will still give me an "Operation failed!" error. This causes confusion, because I don't know if I have entered the right details; which I clearly have but this error overrides the default "Wrong username/password" ones.

```
$custom_text = "You have been banned because of bruteforce attacks.";
$error = new WP_Error();
$error->add('banned_bruteforce', __($custom_text, 'pb'));
return $error;
```

How can I give the above code the highest priority so it will display instead of the "Operation failed!" one?